# Firebase connection is not working with my IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Hey I wanted to connect Ios App to Firebase, I did everything like in the documentation on the website but when I do the last step and want to run the App to connect with the firebase server, it is crashing and this message comes: `` Thread 1: Exception: "`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/." ``
But Why? I have it downloaded and integrated into my project, everything looks like in all the tutorials but it's not working...
And when I open the old blue Xcode project it is throwing this error:
[image]

Here are the references of the new white project, you can see that I have everything:
[image]

I would be really thankful if someone could help me! I just want to go ahead and work on the app:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly says that `it could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist` , rename your file from `GoogleService-Info-2.plist` to `GoogleService-Info.plist` and then it should work.

Comment: Wow thank you, my head was so overloaded that I didn't think about a simple solution like that:D